# low end virtual private server for java development

Tags: java

Will a vps with 360 megs of ram running Linux be able to support a single user developing a java web application that uses Spring, Hibernate, and MySQL for the database? The server will be for development only so the application will not have more then one or two concurrent users.
edit:
By development I mean a server I can deploy and test on. The actual coding will be done on windows, but I want a Linux server to test on as well.

Comment: could you clarify the term "development"?  For most people, it means the workstation you use to create your code and debug your app.  It seems strange to get a VPS (presumably hosted by some 3rd party) to run an IDE (like Justin mentioned) when you could do that on any workstation you have.
Do you prehaps mean the VPS is for deploying your app to and testing it?

Answer (score 2):

This could work ok, but it depends a lot on your application setup. If you cache a lot, your appserver caching page content, Hibernate caching query results/objects or MySQL caching query results you probably will need more RAM. So if your content is big it might not fit, otherwise it might just fit. If you have absulutely no option of increasing the amount of memory if you find out you need more I would certainly not recommend this setup.

But maybe more to the point: What is your target platform? I would say that your server should match that.

Just for linux testing it probably is easier to either get a cheap pc or run it inside a virtual machine on your development machine (assuming you've got plenty of ram on that one).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you're running for your IDE. If you're using Eclipse, you're going to want somewhere around 1Gb of RAM (Eclipse is a memory hog...and slow as all hell if you don't have enough).

If you're using a more efficient (memory wise) IDE, then you should be good to go with that setup for development.

**UPDATE**

Since no coding is going to happen on the box...you should be just fine with that box to do your testing. Enjoy!

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the fact that I don't want to do coding on the VPS, just have another testing platform.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer - I don't think you will have any problems with the amount of ram. I've deployed a rails app to a 256MB VPS and it worked great for development.

Comment: A rails app is different from a java web app in a lot of ways, there is no way you can compare the two in such a way. (Unless you are talking about JRuby on Rails)

Comment: It's 1 or 2 people developing an app. It's going to work fine and even if the box doesn't have enough memory who cares? They're developing.

Comment: If it does not have enough memory they will certainly care since the java virtual machine will start throwing OutOfMemoryExceptions that they cannot fix by assigning a bit more RAM to the JVM.